# Как объединить FileReader и formData

Tags: javascript, jquery

Передо мной встала задача объединить FileReader и formData по отдельности у меня на сайте все работает, но вот вместе не срабатывает, то есть пользователь добавить изображение и как мне отправить в php массивом $_FILES, так же на страницы присутствуют текстовые формы и и радио кнопки с чекбоксами + плюс к тому же если нажал на картинку то она удаляется

```js
var filestoupload = [];
function previewFiles() {

  var preview = document.querySelector('#preview');
  var files = document.querySelector('#browse').files;

  function readAndPreview(file) {

    // Make sure `file.name` matches our extensions criteria
    if (/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
        var image = new Image();
        image.height = 100;
        image.title = file.name;
        image.name = file.name;
        image.src = this.result;
        filestoupload.push(this.result)
        var div= document.createElement('div');
        var divdel= document.createElement('div');
        divdel.className='delete'
        divdel.innerHTML='delete'
        div.className='fileprew'
        div.appendChild(divdel);
        div.appendChild(image);
        preview.appendChild(div);
        console.log('files to upload: ', filestoupload.length)
        
      }, false);

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

  }

  if (files) {
    [].forEach.call(files, readAndPreview);
    
  }

}
$('body').on("click", ".delete", function() {
  
  index=$(this).index();
  console.log('удаляем файл: ',index)
  filestoupload.splice(index, 1);
  $(this).parent().remove();
    $("#browse").val("");
  console.log('files to upload: ', filestoupload.length);
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("form#data").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: "url",
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="data">
<div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                  <label>Добавить изображения объекта</label>
                  <div id="preview"></div>
                  <input type="file" class="photo" id="browse" name="photo[]" value="" onchange="previewFiles()" multiple/>
                                    <p class="help-block">Изображения для слайдера</p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                  <label>Описание проекта</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="description" value="" placeholder="Enter ..."></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="loginform" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-lg">Отправить данные</button>
</form>
```

Comment: По-моему простым ajax тут не обойтись, надо использовать http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload